# how to read a file

Tags: c#

I want to write a function in a way if i call it with an argument
of(100) and the path of particular file it will gets the first 100kb
data of the file, and when i call it for the second time with 200 it should return the next 200kb of data leaving the first 100. If there is no more left in the file it should return 0;

Thanks

Comment: What have YOU done so far? Don't expect people to do your homework for you. At least try it yourself first.

Comment: Write that 100 times on a whiteboard: I will not ask StackOverflow to do my homework.

Comment: How is this 'not a real question'?

Comment: tagged as [beginner]. less of an assumption than [homework] i guess.

Comment: @phoenix - can you imagine an actual real life scenario where "function" as described above would be useful? If you can post it here, not only will I agree that it's a real question, I'll up-vote it.

Comment: @ChssPly76, you have to ask Op to get an the real life scenario.

Comment: I was responding to your "how is this not a real question?" comment. OP's real life scenario is quite obvious - "get SO to do my homework".

Answer (score 2):

most of what you want is handled by the System.IO.File and FileStream. If you want that exact function signature.

Step 1) you need to open a file with a particular path. System.IO.File has a few methods for doing this, including Open and OpenRead, as well as ReadAllXXXX, allowing you to access the flie contents in multiple ways. The one you'd probably want is OpenRead, which returns a FileStream object.

Step 2) you need to read a certain number of bytes. Once you have the FileStream from step 1, you should look at the Stream.ReadBytes method. given an array of bytes, it will read a specified number of bytes from the stream into the array

Answer (score 0):

You may look at the [StreamReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText). It may get you to where you want to go, though I'm not sure of how specifically to break it down into the kb chunks you want.